# Python: getting segmentation fault when using compile/eval

Tags: python, compilation, segmentation-fault, cpython, pypy

Code:

```
import ast

globalsDict = {}

fAst = ast.FunctionDef(
    name="foo",
    args=ast.arguments(args=[], vararg=None, kwarg=None, defaults=[]),
    body=[], decorator_list=[])

exprAst = ast.Interactive(body=[fAst])
ast.fix_missing_locations(exprAst)
compiled = compile(exprAst, "<foo>", "single")
eval(compiled, globalsDict, globalsDict)

print globalsDict["foo"]
```

With both CPython and PyPy, I am getting a segmentation fault. Why?

---

- [CPython bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue12608)
- [PyPy bug report](https://bugs.pypy.org/issue806)
- [Abstract Syntax Trees documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that your function definition must not have an empty body.  I tested your code by adding a no-op statement as the function body:

```
fAst = ast.FunctionDef(
    # ...
    body=[ast.Pass()],
    # ...
```

And the segmentation fault is gone; output is:

```
<function foo at 0x022DB3F0>
```

If I am correct, this could be a bug in the `ast` module, since it should check for the empty body.

Comment: Python gives you a syntax error if you define an empty function without putting `pass` in the body of the function to begin with, does it not?

Comment: It does.  It won't segfault though.

Comment: This is because currently ASTs aren't validated, there's an open ticket in CPython to add a validator to ASTs when you try to compile them to avoid issues like this.